# Is transit visa required for Indian citizen with 23hr transit between Bangkok's two main airports?

Tags: visas, transit, bangkok

I am an Indian passport holder and travelling from Nanjing to Bangkok to Calcutta (all are connecting flight). There is transit at Bangkok (Bangkok Don Mueang International Airport) for 23 hours, then I have a connecting flight to Calcutta from Suvarnabhumi airport. So I need to change the airport. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visa in transit at Suvarnabhumi Airport - Bangkok](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137952/visa-in-transit-at-suvarnabhumi-airport-bangkok)

Comment: @Traveller Not a dup of linked question because this one talks about transit between airports

Comment: @RedBaron Yes, good point, although the answer in the proposed dup covers whether the traveller can stay in the international transit area or not

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do. When changing airports you have to leave the arrival airport's transit area and enter Thailand in order to travel to the departure airport.

https://thailand.travisa.com/Common/TVSVisaInstructions.aspx?citizenshipid=in&countryid=th&residenceid=us&partnerid=ta&glid=aus&travelertypeid=TR

You can try Visa on arrival
http://newdelhi.thaiembassy.org/en/visa-on-arrival-en/